# Aligning cards with list of path elements in custom Kanban component (Aura)

Tags: lightning-aura-components, css, aura-iteration

I'm having some problems with an aura component displaying a custom Kanban view.

I have been able to get the actual logic to work, however, I'm having some trouble with the actual styling/layout of the component. I can't seem to get the cards to show under their respective path element.

I initially tried the following:

```
<div class="slds-grid">
        <div class="slds-path">
            <ul class="slds-path__nav" role="listbox" aria-orientation="horizontal">
                <aura:iteration items="{!v.rows}" var="row">
                        <li class="slds-path__item slds-is-incomplete" role="presentation">
                            <a aria-selected="false" class="slds-path__link">
                                <span class="slds-path__stage" > </span>
                                <span class="slds-path__title">{!row.key.label} </span>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                </aura:iteration>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    
    
    <div class="slds-grid">
        <aura:iteration items="{!v.rows}" var="row">
            <div class="slds-col slds-has-dividers_around-space slds-scrollable_y" data-name="{!row.key.label}" >
                <aura:iteration items="{!row.value}" var="case">
                    <div class="slds-item slds-m-around_xx-small" data-id="{!case.Id}" data-status="{!case.Status}">
                        <div class="slds-tile slds-tile_board">
                            <h3 class="slds-m-around_x-small slds-theme_shade">
                                <div class="slds-grid">
                                    <div class="slds-col">
                                        <div class="slds-m-top_x-small">
                                            <a href="{!'/' + case.Id}" target="_blank">{!case.CaseNumber}</a>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="slds-col slds-text-align_right">
                                        <lightning:buttonGroup >
                                            <lightning:buttonIcon iconName="utility:call" variant="border-filled" alternativeText="Log A Call" onclick="{!c.logACall}" name="{!case.Id}" />
                                            <lightning:buttonIcon iconName="utility:event" variant="border-filled" alternativeText="Log A Meeting" onclick="{!c.logAMeeting}" name="{!case.Id}" />
                                        </lightning:buttonGroup>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </h3>
                            
                            <div class="slds-tile__detail slds-text-body_small">
                                <p class="slds-truncate">
                                    {!case.Subject}
                                </p>
                                
                                <p class="slds-truncate">
                                    {!case.Project_Job_Name__c}
                                </p>
                                
                                <p class="slds-truncate">
                                    {!case.OwnerId}
                                </p>
                                
                                <p class="slds-truncate">
                                    {!case.Due_date__c}
                                </p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </aura:iteration> 
            </div>
        </aura:iteration> 
    </div>
```

Resulting in the path and the cards basically being separated (looking like this):
[image]

I also tried this:

```
<div class="slds-grid">
        <div class="slds-path">
                    <div class="slds-grid ">
                        <aura:iteration items="{!v.rows}" var="row">
                            <div class="slds-col slds-has-dividers_around-space slds-scrollable_y"  >
                                <ul class="slds-path__nav" role="listbox" aria-orientation="horizontal">
                                    <li class="slds-path__item slds-is-incomplete" role="presentation">
                                        <a aria-selected="false" class="slds-path__link">
                                            <span class="slds-path__stage" > </span>
                                            <span class="slds-path__title">{!row.key.label} </span>
                                        </a>
                                        
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                                <aura:iteration items="{!row.value}" var="case">
                                    <div class="slds-item slds-m-around_xx-small" data-id="{!case.Id}" data-status="{!case.Status}">
                                        <div class="slds-tile slds-tile_board">
                                            <h3 class="slds-m-around_x-small slds-theme_shade">
                                                <div class="slds-grid">
                                                    <div class="slds-col">
                                                        <div class="slds-m-top_x-small">
                                                            <a href="{!'/' + case.Id}" target="_blank">{!case.CaseNumber}</a>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                    <div class="slds-col slds-text-align_right">
                                                        <lightning:buttonGroup >
                                                            <lightning:buttonIcon iconName="utility:call" variant="border-filled" alternativeText="Log A Call" onclick="{!c.logACall}" name="{!case.Id}" />
                                                            <lightning:buttonIcon iconName="utility:event" variant="border-filled" alternativeText="Log A Meeting" onclick="{!c.logAMeeting}" name="{!case.Id}" />
                                                        </lightning:buttonGroup>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </h3>
                                            
                                            <div class="slds-tile__detail slds-text-body_small">
                                                <p class="slds-truncate">
                                                    {!case.Subject}
                                                </p>
                                                
                                                <p class="slds-truncate">
                                                    {!case.Project_Job_Name__c}
                                                </p>
                                                
                                                <p class="slds-truncate">
                                                    {!case.OwnerId}
                                                </p>
                                                <p class="slds-truncate">
                                                    {!case.Status}
                                                </p>
                                                <p class="slds-truncate">
                                                    {!case.Due_date__c}
                                                </p>
                                                
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </aura:iteration> 
                            </div>
                        </aura:iteration> 
                    </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

With the latest attempt, it seems that the different path elements are unable to identify their part in the path (they all become pill-shaped):
[image]

Any help on this would be greatly apprechiated. More Details can be provided if neccessary